# Using resource files in python (pytest) tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Could someone tell me what the correct way of dealing with resource files in pytest?

I have a habit of creating a resources directory just under the package (src) directory and another under the test branch

```
root---package---resource_dir
     |         |-file1.py
     |         |-file2.py
     |
     |-test-- resource_dir-
            |              |-config1.csv
            |              |-config2.csv
            |-test1.py
            |-test2.py
```

If I want to access these files from within my tests what is the pythonic way of doing so? Up to now I have been using relative file paths but that solution isn't great. Is there a solution similar to the Java resources solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I have found to do this is using pkg_resources. This has the ability to search through your package for files. So, for example, if you want to print the contents of a file that is in the test resources directory you could do the following:

```
import pkg_resources
config_file = open(pkg_resources.resource_filename('test.resources','config.csv'),'r')
    for line in config_file:
        print(line)

    print(">>>End of File")
```

please note that all directories and subdirectories need to be pacakges (i.e the **init**.py file must be present, even if its empty).

Answer (score 3):

If all your files belong to the same package, then you can use importlib instead of pkg_resources.

According to the official documentation this provides less overhead and better performance.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.files

If you have trouble importing from a sibling package, please read the excellent answer here:
[Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Example:

```
# import test.resource_dir as a namespace package. 
# add a __init__.py to your directory if you want to turn it into a regular package

import test.resource_dir  
from importlib.resources import files
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def config_path():
    return files(test.resource_dir).joinpath("config1.csv")

def test_read_config(config_path):
    with open(config_path, 'r') as config:
        assert config.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the root folder and test/resource_dir to the sys.path. This will allow you to always include resources in the exact same way no matter what the directory structure of your test folder currently looks like.

Adding the root folder to sys.path also helps create consistency between the test runner and normal execution, and will allow your tests to directly reference resources from `root/package/resource_directory`.

Adding `test/resource_dir` to sys.path allows tests to directly reference resources from `test/resource_dir`.

For some sample code on how to set this up, see Option B on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498390/using-pytest-where-test-in-subfolder/51334378#51334378), but with replacing the `lib` folder for `resource_dir`.